How should "爆心点より上昇" be translated in this sentence?
I want to translate the sentence "爆心点より上昇してくる物体があります" and am wondering whether "より" should be translated as "from" or if "より上" should instead be translated as "above." Should the full sentence be more like "there is an object rising above the center of the explosion" or "there is an object rising from the center of the explosion"? The reason this distinction kinda matters is because it seems to determine whether or not the object was definitively at the center of the explosion when it went off (please correct me if I'm wrong on that conclusion).

The sentence is "There is an object rising from the center of the explosion". The word after より is 上昇【じょうしょう】(する), not 上【うえ】.

So that means the object had to have been at the center of the explosion when the explosion went off, right?

@jakub414 Yes. It could be either that something like a cannonball has been fired from the explosive center, or that the projectile itself is a rocket-like explosive.

The object is a ship. It cannot have escaped the center of the explosion right before the explosion went off, could it?

^ @jakub414 Is this sentence from a fictional work? The "ship" is an airship, right?

@jakub414 All we can tell from this sentence is that something is approaching upwards from the epicenter. It doesn't specify whether the ship is being passively ejected by the explosion or actively using its engines to escape.

Yeah it's a fictional airship. Someone tried to kill the people in the airship with the explosion, but I'm trying to determine whether they escaped the center of the explosion before the explosion or just survived being hit by the explosion and escaped the center of it after it went off. In Japanese, is it grammatically possible to come out "from" the center of an explosion before the explosion itself actually starts to exist? Sorry about all these weird questions.

@jakub414 This sentence is only saying that someone just noticed some object is currently approaching from the epicenter. From this sentence alone, no one can tell whether it's a destroyed ship or a working ship. No one can tell whether the airship departed before the explosion, either; that’s a past event observed by no one.

Again, sorry about all these comments. Anyways, the ship was a working ship flying out of the explosion. Is it possible that the ship departed before the explosion? Can a ship depart "from" the center of a future explosion before it even happens? Or does that not make sense in Japanese?
